# what size battery storage is needed to provide 10A at 115v for 5 continuous hours

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell

I have a two part question:

1. What size battery storage is needed to provide 10A at 115v (I meant 115v AC) for 5 continuous hours?
2. what size solar array (assuming proper alignment, etc.) would be required to charge the battery bank each day during the summer months?

Comment: You need a 115V battery with 50 Amp-hours of capacity, and your solar panels should provide an average of 1150 Watt for 5 hours each day to break even.

Comment: Did you assume AC or DC?  or consider cloudy days excess storage?

Comment: Hi Terry H, please check out this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/104357/38335) I wrote for a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

1. From basic physics, (10 A)(115 V)(5 h) = 5750 Watt-hours.  That's what the system has to cough up.  The battery would have to store a bit more than that due to the converter from battery to 115 V AC having some loss.

   There are many variables here, not the least of which are what daily insolation you expect the system to be able to recharge a empty battery with.  For example, let's say you decide to require 3 hours of full sun.  (5750 Wh)/(3 h) = 1.9 kW.  Let's say that together the converter from solar panel to battery, and the efficiency of the battery, and the efficiency of the inverter is 50%.  That means you need about 4 kW capability in full sun.

The answer to both these questions really comes down to *"Do the math!"*.